# how can i download rna-seq data sample for starting rna-seq analysis by R?

Tags: r, rna-seq

I am looking for an induction into RNA-seq analysis using R. I have yet to decide a data set, or a  subject area. Any help in this regard would be welcome.

Comment: Hi @Aminafzalifar welcome to the forum! My advice is have a think about what to focus on and return with a better defined question. Can you code, do you understand dataframes? Sauret and Bioconductor are popular packages in R which deal with this, however in my opinion (not universally shared) you need a local supervisor to help you.

Comment: I'm sorry, but we don't do this sort of open-ended discussion here. This site isn't a forum, it's strictly a questions & answers site and we only cover _specific_ questions that can have _specific_ answers. Your question is just too broad for this site's format. You might want to take the [tour] or visit our [help] to understand how the site works. Especially [this](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) page that explains the kind of question to avoid.

Comment: thanks and sorry about my bad question.

Answer (score 2):

You must have found the airway dataset by googling "RNASeq R tutorial"

https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/workflows/vignettes/rnaseqGene/inst/doc/rnaseqGene.html

Why won't this work for you?